# Removing selected markers from google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-markers

I am placing multiple markers on google map by using onMarkerClickListener, now I want to give user the option to remove any marker from the added markers. Can anyone suggest some way to do this.

my code for marker is

```
 GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener listener = new            
GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        AddGeofenceFragment dFragment = new AddGeofenceFragment();
        // Show DialogFragment
        dFragment.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");
        return true;
    }

};

newmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);

newmap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

        // Creating a marker
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position for the marker
        markerOptions.position(latLng);

        // Setting the title for the marker.
        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);


        // Animating to the touched position
        newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Placing a marker on the touched position
        newmap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        Log.d("ADDED LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.latitude));
        Log.d("ADDED LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Block area updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by implementing interface OnMarkerClickListener to the mapActivity. then you need to write your require code to delete the selected marker in the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    if (marker.equals(myMarker)) {
        //handle click here
        marker.remove();
    }
}
```